# User feedback integration with Azure DevOps (VSTS)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, issue-tracking

I am just wondering if there is an easier way to integrate VSTS issue management with the application I am developing. Something what MS has done for their docs with Github.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1gAp.jpg)

I am aware that there are rest api's which we can use but just wondering if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this feature can only be achieved through the rest api. Even in Github, the underlying layer grabs the feedback in the UI through the rest api.

If you think using the rest api is not a convenient way, I recommend that you could submit a suggestion ticket to suggest the new feature.This could promote development of richer features. You could click into “Suggest a feature” as shown in the screenshot or go to this url: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 directly.
[image]

**Note**: After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to [Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com) then you can relatively easily integrate it with DevOps. There are several templates that allow automatic capture and creation of work items, shouldn't be much harder to hook into the updated events.